# VB.Net Button access

Tags: vb.net, button, for-loop, coordinates

I have a question about VB.net.
In this code, there is a creation of 64 buttons (by for-loop). How can I access a button, in the Klik method and made in zetnieuw, by its coordinates? Because, basically the zetnieuw function is just to make the buttons.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim AANTAL_KOLOMMEN As Integer = 8
Dim AANTAL_RIJEN As Integer = 8
Dim Button1 As Button
Dim tel As Boolean
Dim value1 As Integer
Dim value2 As Integer




Public Function zetNieuw(rij As Integer, kolom As Integer) As Button
    Dim nieuweKnop As New Button()
    nieuweKnop.Width = 40
    Me.Controls.Add(nieuweKnop)
    nieuweKnop.Left = kolom * nieuweKnop.Width
    nieuweKnop.Top = rij * nieuweKnop.Width
    nieuweKnop.Height = nieuweKnop.Width
    nieuweKnop.Text = ""
    AddHandler nieuweKnop.MouseDown, AddressOf Klik
    ...
    nieuweKnop.Tag = (kolom + (rij * AANTAL_KOLOMMEN))
    Return nieuweKnop


End Function


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Me.value1 = 1 To AANTAL_KOLOMMEN Step 1
        For Me.value2 = 1 To AANTAL_RIJEN Step 1
            Me.zetNieuw(value2, value1)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub Klik(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    Dim knop As Button = sender
    ...
End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure about what are you asking for. Do You want to access to the button in the klik event handler (thats is catching the click event)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by access, the button that was clicked is the sender that you are putting into your knop variable, the coordinates are present there, if you are wanting to say myButtons(x)(y) and return your button, you will need to create an array and place them into that.

Comment: I tried to create an array, but I got an nullreferenceexception error.
I want to access a button that I made in zetnieuw, in the click event handler, yes.

Comment: In your click event handler, the sender parameter will be the button that was clicked and you can then view the properties of the button, just as @MekoPerezEstevez said.

Comment: Basically I need to acces 3 buttons. 1 with the tag (button I click) and the 2 buttons next to it. I understnad how ot use the button with the tag, but I need to acccess the other two buttons on another way.
For example, when I click a button, the button next to it gains the same backcolor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work,  declare your array like this

```
Dim myButtons(AANTAL_KOLOMMEN - 1, AANTAL_RIJEN - 1) As Button
```

fill it like this, be aware that arrays are zero based in .Net:

```
For Me.value1 = 0 To AANTAL_KOLOMMEN - 1 Step 1
    For Me.value2 = 0 To AANTAL_RIJEN - 1 Step 1
        myButtons(value2, value1) = Me.zetNieuw(value2, value1)
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Ty! Gonna try this when I`m at home.

Comment: I got an error if I add tag/AANTAL_KOLOMMEN as row and tag mod AANTAL_KOLOMMEN as column to a mybutton. Index out of bounds it says. I guess that has to do with my tag?

Comment: Remember that you will need to adjust you values to compensate the fact the array is zero based not one based. I.e column 8 is actually seven, column one is actually zero.  You are probably being tripped up at the extents of your array

Answer (score 0):

When creating the button in zetNieuw, you could set the Name property of the button to a value that contains row and column, e.g.

```
nieuweKnop.Name = "btn_" & rij & "_" & kolom
```

You can use the name of the button to [find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28VS.80%29.aspx) a specific button by row and column later on, if you follow the same convention. Also, you can determine row and column upon the Name property if you have a specific button.

```
Dim parts = btn.Name.Split("_"C)
Dim row = Integer.Parse(parts(1))
Dim col = Integer.Parse(parts(2))
```

If it is only about the later (retrieving row and column based upon a button object), analyze the Tag property that you already set in zetNieuw.